# How do I convert an <any> handleChange Function from class to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, event-handling

I'm trying to convert an existing react class to a functional component. I understand that functions use the `useState()` function rather than `setState()` like in a class. How would I convert this piece of code that handles the change of any input into a functional piece?

```
handleChange = (input) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
  };
```

Comment: functional component also use setState.. it uses something like this: const [x, setX] = useState(0); where 0 is the initial value of x

Comment: @GlenK I get that but how do you make it dynamic to work with multiple different inputs without having to explicitly create variables like that?

Comment: normally I create one const for every variable.. say if I have name, address, phone.. I will have const [name, setName], const [address, setAddress], const [phone, setPhone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a different `useState` hook for each field, but you don't have to.  You can keep your setup almost the same as in your class component by using a single `state` object to hold all fields.  The primary difference is that with `useState` you have to provide the entire state, so you need to use `...state` to include the unchanged properties.

```
const Form = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    first: "",
    last: "",
    address: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (input: keyof typeof state) => 
    (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      setState({
        ...state,
        [input]: e.target.value
      });
    };

  return (
    <form>
      <input value={state.first} onChange={handleChange("first")} />
      <input value={state.last} onChange={handleChange("last")} />
      <input value={state.address} onChange={handleChange("address")} />
    </form>
  );
};
```